# Clicking link in Thunderbird opens browser but doesn't enter URL

Tags: chromium, thunderbird, browser, url

I'm trying to fix this behavior, which isn't the default behavior. Clicking a link in an email message in Thunderbird 45.5.1 under Ubuntu 16 opens my Chromium 55.0 browser, but doesn't enter the URL in the address bar.

I've already checked the `network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http` and `.https` and `network.protocol-handler.external-default` settings in the Thunderbird config; they're all `true`.

I can't determine where this behavior would be controlled. Any suggestions where I should start looking?

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

-Kevin

Answer (score 0):

If Thunderbird doesn't ask you which browser to use when you click on a link, you can try deleting ( or edit and modify for your browser and path) mimeTypes.rdf file in your profile folder (./thunderbird in your home) to reset it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem is not that Thunderbird opens the wrong browser. It opens the correct (default, Chromium) browser, but doesn't paste in the URL. I have to manually right-click on the URL in the email message, select 'Copy link address', then right-click in the address bar of Chromium and select 'Paste and go'.

Thanks, again, for responding.

Comment: Also, for others following along at home, the file is at ~/.thunderbird/<rand_char>.default/mimeTypes.rfd. However, I couldn't find anything like 'chrome' or 'chromium' when searching and ignoring case.